# SSRS Display list of distinct values and totals from another column for those values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subtotal, group-summaries

This seems like something that should be so very simple and easy but I'm completely missing it. I've got a set of transactions I'm trying to report on. Each has a set of data that I'm displaying grouped by a business date. Two parts of this are card type and amount.

What I want to do is for each Business Date group, below the list of transactions, display a totals summary which would look something like:

[date]

Transaction 1 Visa ...... amount .....

Transaction 2 Debit ...... amount .....

Transaction 3 Visa ...... amount .....

Transaction 4 Debit ...... amount .....

Transaction 5 Debit ...... amount .....

Transaction 6 Discover ...... amount .....

Transaction 7 Gift Card ...... amount .....

Transaction 8 Visa ...... amount .....

Transaction 9 Discover ...... amount .....

Transaction 10 Visa ...... amount .....

Summary of totals for [date]

Visa - $xxxx.xx

Discover - $xxxx.xx

Debit - $xxxx.xx

...

Total - $xxxx.xx

Preferably getting each value programmatically instead of manually setting up each cell for each card. I've seen some answers on the totals expressions side but not the distinct values part and those answers would have me manually set up each individual cell.

Comment: When you say "distinct" do you actually mean grouping the data? If you group by card type inside the business date group you should get the wanted output.

Comment: Didn't really want to break up the list more than just by the date. I don't have any feedback on how they need it sorted so for now I was hoping to keep it all one block of data and then just a separate section with the totals.

Comment: You're kind of confusing me now, where do you wish to have this summary exactly? Do you want a different summary for each day or only the total at the end? It still seems to me that a simple grouping by card type is all that's required to get a similar summary. If you add a visual representation of what you have right now followed by an image of what you're trying to achieve, I might be able to give you more accurate advice.

Comment: Tried to elaborate on my example. to make it more clear. Each page contains one dates worth of transactions. At the bottom of the page for that one date I would place the summary section. There are various other colums they can sort the data by other than just card type and amount. I want to preserve those sorting options.

Answer (score 0):

As you wish to have a single page for each date, you could place your original table inside a `Rectangle` and group the rectangle by date. This will allow you to define a page break to get a single page for each transaction day, but you can also have multiple days on a single page based on your preference.
You should be able to remove the grouping by date from the table because it'll just inherit the grouping from the rectangle.
Next you can add a second table below your original table (inside the rectangle) and define a new row group by card type. Because your rectangle is already grouping the data by date, this will again be inherited and you should get the correct `Sum` values for each total.

I hope this clears things up for you, if it doesn't just leave a comment and I'll edit where necessary.